# Restricting service account access within a service

Tags: google-cloud-run, service-accounts

Background:

I have 2 services, A and B, both requiring access to service X, all running on Cloud Run.
Service X requires authentication, since both A and B have their own service accounts, I gave them the invoker role on service X, made sure access tokens are set on headers, so everything works.

Actual question:

I want to restrict access to specific APIs within service X. Ex: I want Service A to be able to only use READ endpoints, but B to be able to also use WRITE endpoints.
Is there any way to include custom scopes or claims to access tokens generated by GCP from service accounts so I can have granular access control at the API level?

Note: I come from an Azure background, where we could setup and API with scopes, and assign those scopes to accounts. Trying to understand if there's an equivalent on GCP.

Comment: IAM service manage permissions for Google Cloud. Here you want custom permissions for your service. IAM is not designed for that, and you can't manage this type of custom permissions. You can add a software framework to manage that, or use an API gateway to add this kind of restriction.

Answer (score -1):

In gcp we can create a custom role service account while calling API, In your case you need to create 2 service account with custom role, one with viewer role and other with writer or editor role.

Here is a [blog](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/prisma/prisma-cloud/prisma-cloud-admin/connect-your-cloud-platform-to-prisma-cloud/onboard-your-gcp-account/create-custom-role-on-gcp) explaining the process of creating a service account with custom roles.

While calling an API make sure you are using the correct service accounts for performing read and write operations respectively.

Comment: This is to give access a service account access to various GCP services, not a custom service,

Comment: @ESG What do you mean by custom service?,”I have assumed service x as a tool which needs to modify or read services  in gcp, So,  it requires a service account,” based on this assumption I have provided the answer.

Comment: I want to limit access within my own service

Comment: If you're using your own services and you want to authenticate these services using Google, you need to use google Oauth 2.0 for authentication. This [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) will help you to understand and implement the google Oauth services.